# Removing white line in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a navbar with bootstrap and the dropdown menu has a white line at the top and bottom. I want the whole dropdown to be the same color but can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the white lines. BTW I'm a beginner coder and this navbar was straight copied and pasted from getboostrap so if anything is looking wrong please let me know thank you!
[Here is a picture of the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWld4.png)

Here's my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color:#3d3d3d">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="https://marginedge.com/" target="_blank">
  <img src="navbarLogo.png" width="200">
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Flow <span class="sr-only">(current) 
</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Map</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">EDI Tracker</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">D.C. Sales</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Zendesk</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Client Facing
    </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Isabella</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Eggspectation</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ford's</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hard Rock</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wendy's</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Demos</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Analyst
    </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">IR Error Report</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rec Error Report</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Quarterly Team Evaluations</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Data Fixer for Analysts</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Redash</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Central Data Health Check</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-lg-2" type="search" size="40" placeholder="Search Redash Reports..." aria-label="Search">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and here's is the CSS:

```
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
nav {
width: 100%;
}
nav ul li{
padding: 5px 10px;
font-size: 20px;
}
.dropdown-menu a{
font-size: 15px;
color: #d6d6d6;
background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
```

Comment: You changed the background-color of "dropdown-menu a" but not the background-color of "dropdown-menu" itself.That means it remains default.

Comment: when I change the background-color for "dropdown-menu" it doesn't do anything. only when i place it in "dropdown-menu a" does the background color actually change

Comment: selecting the right element is the key to changing the properties. Right click on the white space and inspect the element. There it should tell you element and the properties it has.

Comment: Do you have a URL or is this hosted locally? I'm only asking because some of us can help more if we can inspect your elements. Generally this is caused by two different things, 1) You have a padding-top/padding-bottom at the ul level. 2) You are changing the background of the list item or "li" but not changing it at the ul level.

Comment: I figured it out. Just had to add "style=background-color" in the "div class=dropdown-menu" line. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @MilanMalhotra wait! You did that inline? as in <div style="background-color:"> </div>?

Comment: Yeah I put the style inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add`p-0` class on .dropdown-menu. It will remove he padding causing the white space

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #d6d6d6;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color:#3d3d3d">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://marginedge.com/" target="_blank">
    <img src="navbarLogo.png" width="200">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Flow <span class="sr-only">(current) 
</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Map</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">EDI Tracker</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">D.C. Sales</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Zendesk</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Client Facing
</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu p-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Isabella</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Eggspectation</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ford's</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hard Rock</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wendy's</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Demos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Analyst
</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu p-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">IR Error Report</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rec Error Report</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Quarterly Team Evaluations</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Data Fixer for Analysts</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Redash</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Central Data Health Check</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-lg-2" type="search" size="40" placeholder="Search Redash Reports..." aria-label="Search">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```